# How do I make my scrollbar always visible within tableview iOS(Swift AutoLayout)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I need to modify my scrollbar(tableView Scrollbar) which supports following features like,

1.Scrollbar must be **visible** always  (I don’t know how to use flashindicators)
2.Scrollbar also need to have **drag ability** for **fast scrolling** between cells,

I don’t know how to do that ,so anyone pls suggest with pods similar like swiftyverticalscrollbar or any other open source projects
[image: reference screenshot]
I also attached screenshot for the feature which I am expecting

Comment: i used swiftyverticalscrollbar and also SwiftlyScrollSlider but both wont work as per expectation.problem with using swiftyverticalscrollbar is i cant click cells inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its simple try it using `'SwiftyVerticalScrollBar'` , you can read its details [here](https://github.com/satoshin2071/SwiftyVerticalScrollBar)

using this framework you can add custom scrollbar and you can do changes acordingly.

i hope i will helpful for you ...:)

[edited]

try this for set scrollbar proerly

```
let newX = self.view.bounds.size.width-10
self.scrollBar.frame = CGRect(x: newX, y: 0, width: 10, height: self.view.bounds.size.height)
```

along with above codes,i added below code for hiding default scrollbar

`tableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false`

`tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false`

Comment: ya thanks for the quick reply ,i tried this pod which has similar feature as per my expectation but the main problem using this one was , i cant click cells inside it while using SwiftyVerticalScrollBar

Comment: try to give fix width to scrollview `self.scrollBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: self.view.bounds.size.height)`

Comment: scrollbar appear on left side instead of right side,if we giving width as 10,and also default scrollbar visible so seems two scrollbar were showing

Comment: ya i can able to click cells inside it ,but can u pls explain how can i show scrollbar on right side instead of left side while give width as 10